# Does basis of $A$ in $4$ dimensions, make basis for $B$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, proof-explanation, examples-counterexamples

Suppose that {$x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$} is a basis for a vector space $A$ . Suppose that $B$ is a subspace of $A$, and that $x_1, x_2 ∈ B$ but $x_3 ∉ B$ and $x_4 ∉ B$. Is it true that {$x_1, x_2$} is a basis for $B$?

If this is true, then I need to write a proof but if it's not, then a counterexample should suffice right? I not sure if it's true, I thought it wasn't but I'm having a hard time coming up with a counterexample so now I'm thinking that it is true.

Here's what I have so far: Consider where $A = R^4$. So, the basis has $4$ vectors and the vectors in a basis must be linearly independent and span. Let the basis of $R^4$ be {$x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$}  so $B$ is given by {$x_1,x_2$}, so $B$ has dimension of 2, so it's in $R^2$. If $B$ is $R^2$, then standard basis of $B$ is {$i,j$}, but, if the vectors from the basis of $R^4$ have $4$ components, each, $x_1$ and $x_2$ are not in $R^2$ since they have more than $2$ components. So it's not a basis of $B$.

I'm not really sure if this is the right way to go about the question and counterexample. If it's true, how could I do a proof for it and how do I know it's true? Thanks.
(I'm starting to think it's true but I'm pretty confused)

Edit: I just tried to answer this, so please refer to the answer section to give me feedback. Thanks!

Comment: Try a simpler case first. Let $\{x_1,x_2\}$ be a basis for a two-dimensional space $A$. Then let $B$ be a one-dimensional subspace of $A$. Is $B$ necessarily spanned by either $x_1$ or $x_2$? How many such subspaces $B$ are there?

Comment: Consider $A=\mathbb R^4$ with the standard basis, and $B$ spanned by $(1,0,0,0), (0,1,0,0)$, and $(0,0,1,1)$

Comment: @march So here $x_1$ would be a basis for b?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner So if $B$ is spanned by $x_1 = (1,0,0,0)$ and $x_2 = (0,1,0,0) $, then they do span for $B$? So the statement was true?

Comment: Consider the standard plane $x_1$ is directional vector for axis $X$ and $x_2$ one for $Y$. If you take a random straight line (subspace of dim 1) it is not necessarily parallel to the axis $X$ or $Y$, so neither of $x_1,x_2$ is a basis for it. Maybe this is more clearer this way.

Comment: If $x_1$ or $x_2$ are the only choices for the span of $B$, how many one-dimensional subspaces of $A$ would there then be? And can that possibly be correct?

Comment: In my example, $B$ is not spanned by $x_1$ and $x_2$, because $B$ contains $(0,0,1,1)$

Comment: @zwim So to apply that thinking towards $R^4$, if I take $(i, j, k, l)$ as the vectors for the basis of $R^4 = A$, then $B=(i,j)$ and $i, j$ are not the basis for some subspace $B$, since they don't span $B$? I'm having a hard time visualizing it with the dimensions.

Comment: @march if they're the only choices for span $B$, then there's only one subspace $B$ of $A$, which is not correct? So they don't necessarily make the basis for $B$?

Comment: Well, there would be only *two* one-dimensional subspaces of $B$, one spanned by $x_1$ and one spanned by $x_2$. And then, I want you to *answer* this question: are there are only two one-dimensional subspaces? *How many* one-dimensional subspaces are there in a two-dimensional vector space? Take the concrete example of $\mathbb{R}^2$. What, geometrically, is a one-dimensional subspace? How many are there?

Comment: @march so for subspaces of $R^2$, there is the zero subspace, $R^2$ itself, and all the lines through the origin. The lines would be the one dimensional subspaces, and there are infinite amount of possible lines that can go through the origin. Is this right?

Comment: Yep! And so the individual spans of $x_1$ and $x_2$ can't possibly give you all subspaces, and so a one-dimensional subspaces of $B$ might have neither $x_1$ nor $x_2$ in it! From there, use the other comments to zero in on  the answer to your question. Once you figure it out, I encourage you to write an answer here!

Comment: @march thanks! can I write an answer for my own question below, or am I supposed to put it with the question? (Sorry I'm new to mathstack)

Comment: Self-answers are generally encouraged (well at least on the other stack exchange sites I regularly post on).  Don't edit your question!  Post an answer below.

Comment: @march How's my answer? Did I do it?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner is my answer correct as I put below?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $B = \operatorname{span}\{x_1,x_2,x_3+x_4\}$. Since $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, and $x_4$ form a basis for $A$, they are all linearly independent and hence so are $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3+x_4$. The span $B$ is then a three-dimensional subspace of $A$.

Now, neither $x_3$ nor $x_4$ are in $B$. To show this by way of contradiction, assume $x_3\in B$. Then there exists $a_1$, $a_2$, and $a_3$ in the field such that
$$
x_3=a_1x_1+a_2x_2+a_3(x_3+x_4)\,.
$$
Rearranging, we can write this as
$$
0=a_1x_1+a_2x_2+(a_3-1)x_3+a_3x_4\,.
$$
Since the $x_i$'s are linearly independent, all of these coefficients must be zero, which means that $a_1=0$, $a_2=0$, $a_3-1=0$, and $a_3=0$. But this is a contradiction because the last two equalities say that $0=a_3=1$. Thus $x_3$ is not in the span of $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3+x_4$ and is therefore not in $B$. The same argument works for $x_4$.

Thus, $B$ is a proper subspace of $A$ containing neither $x_3$ nor $x_4$, but it is not spanned by $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that {$x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$} is a basis for a vector space $A$ . Suppose that $B$ is a subspace of $A$, and that $x_1, x_2 ∈ B$ but $x_3 ∉ B$ and $x_4 ∉ B$. Is it true that {$x_1, x_2$} is a basis for $B$?

This is not true. Have that a set of vectors form a basis if they are linearly independent and span the vector space. Since {$x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$} for $A$ are linearly independent, we know that {$x_1, x_2$} are also linearly independent for B. Now it remains to show that {$x_1, x_2$} are not a span for $B$. Consider the situation where $A=R^4$, with basis {$x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$} and some subspace $B$. Let  {$x_1, x_2$} = {$(0,0,0,2), (0,0,2,0)$}. For this to span $B$, all of $B$ must be expressed as a linear combination of vectors {$(0,0,0,2), (0,0,2,0)$}. Now consider when $B$ is some subspace of $R^4$, where  $(2,0,0,2)$ is an element of the subspace $B$. $(2,0,0,2)$ can't be expressed as a linear combination of {$(0,0,0,2), (0,0,2,0)$}, so {$(0,0,0,2), (0,0,2,0)$} does not span $B$, so it's not a basis of $B$.

Can I get some feedback on this answer? I want to show a solid counterexample. Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to exhibit an *explicit* example of $B$. You've said that $x_1$, $x_2$, and this third vector $(2,0,0,2)$ is in the space, but you haven't specified what the entirety of $B$ is. Furthermore, you have to construct $B$ such that $x_3$ and $x_4$ aren't in $B$, but you haven't even said what $x_3$ and $x_4$ are! I recommend taking the canonical basis $x_1=(1,0,0,0)$, $x_2=(0,1,0,0)$, $x_3=(0,0,1,0,)$, $x_4=(0,0,0,1)$ and construct $B$ explicitly as the span of three vectors $x_1$, $x_2$, and some third one. Then show that with that choice, 3 and 4 aren't in there but it's still 3D

Comment: I'll write an answer with an abstract version of this problem. Then look at it and see if you can patch up your answer with an explicit example in $\mathbb{R}^4$ using the canonical basis and an explicit choice of subspace $B$!

Comment: @march alright thanks! I'll look at your example and come up with a better answer.